# How to make a redirection and then refresh the target page?

Tags: php, redirect, reload

I have an issue when I use the CRUD in PHP.
I created a delete page, and when the code is over, I put the redirection to another page.
To do so, I need to refresh manually the target page, to see the result.

For now, i'm using this code:

```
header("Location: www.mysite.com/page5.php");
```

I'm looking for a way to make the redirection and to refresh the target page once.

edit:
I understand that you need my code to understand my problem.
Here is my first file (new_card.php):

```
    <table>
     ...
       <td>
          <a href="edit/Edit_Cards_New.php?id=<?= $queries['id_img_et_contenu']; ?>">
           <img src="img/icons/edit.png" width="50px" alt="edit icon">
          </a>
       </td>
       <td>
         <a href="delete/delete_Cards_New.php?id=<?= $queries['id_img_et_contenu']; ?>">
            <img src="img/icons/delete.png" width="50px" alt="delete icon">
         </a>
                                   
       </td>
     </tr>
       ...
    </table>
```

Then, the delete file :

```
    <?php
    
    include '../connect.php';
    
    $sql = "DELETE FROM the_table_new
            WHERE id_img_et_contenu = :id_img_et_contenu";
    
    $request = $bdd->prepare($sql);
    $request->bindParam(':id_img_et_contenu', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $request->execute();
    
    ?>
    
    <script>
       window.location = "../new_card.php"
    </script>
```

Here is my problem, because I want the file new_card.php reload once after the redirection to take effect. I hope this helped you!

Thanks in advance .

Bye.

Comment: You mean it's redirecting you to page5.php but you don't see the information you're expecting until you manually refresh it again? If so then it's probably a browser caching issue. Maybe set a no-cache header on page5 to stop browsers caching the result and/or prevent your server serving a cached version.

Comment: Hi ADyson, you understood my issue. By the way, it's not the cache, because I automatically delete it. For example, in my backoffice, I delete something, the redirection goes to page5.php of my backoffice without any change. To see something, I need to refresh manually the page.

Comment: Hm. We'll need a [mre] of the issue then I think, it's impossible to tell what's going on based on a single line of code and a fairly high-level description.